# How can I pattern match on a HttpMethod in F#?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Where `request` is a `HttpRequestMessage` from `System.Net.Http`, I'm trying to use pattern matching to determine which method was used to make the request.

This is a contrived example which demonstrates my problem:

```
let m = match request.Method with
      | HttpMethod.Get -> "GET"
      | HttpMethod.Post -> "POST"
```

which results in:

> **Parser error**: The field, constructor or member 'Get' is not defined

Why doesn't this work, and how can I use pattern matching or a more appropriate technique to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Something like `| t when t = HttpMethod.Get`  whould work.  This is required as `Get` is not a literal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As John Palmer points out in his comment, you could write it like this:

```
let m =
    match request.Method with
    | x when x = HttpMethod.Get -> "GET"
    | x when x = HttpMethod.Post -> "POST"
    | _ -> ""
```

However, if you're going to be doing this repeatedly, you may find this a bit cumbersome, in which case you could define some [Active Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) for it:

```
let (|GET|_|) x =
    if x = HttpMethod.Get
    then Some x
    else None

let (|POST|_|) x =
    if x = HttpMethod.Post
    then Some x
    else None
```

Which would enable you to write this:

```
let m =
    match request.Method with
    | GET _ -> "GET"
    | POST _ -> "POST"
    | _ -> ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with Active Patterns which ends up with a slightly nicer code than in Mark's solution would be a pattern function like this one (using full classification pattern):

```ml
let (|GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|OTHER|) x =
    if x = HttpMethod.Get
    then GET
    elif x = HttpMethod.Post
    then POST
    elif x = HttpMethod.Put
    then PUT
    elif x = HttpMethod.Delete
    then DELETE
    else OTHER
```

This approach lets you get rid of underscores in pattern matching:

```ml
let m =
    match request.Method with
    | GET -> "GET"
    | POST -> "POST"
    | _ -> ""
```